# 'Raycast' is not being recognized within C# Unity script

Tags: c#, augmented-reality

I'm following a Unity Augmented Reality Tutorial using ARFoundation (I've made sure the package has installed correctly, along with ARkit).

My code follows his to the letter, and yet Raycast does not appear to be recognized. I get this error when I hover over it:

> 'ARSessionOrigin' does not contain a definition for 'Raycast' and no accessible extension method 'Raycast' accepting a first argument of type 'ARSessionOrigin' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can't figure out what the issue is, and I've redone the tutorial twice now (the second time using Unity's 3D template instead of ARCore because it seemed that ARFoundation was locked when I used ARCore template.) I'd greatly appreciate if someone could take a look and let me know if they have an idea of how to resolve it.

Thinking it had to do with ARFoundation not installing correctly, I double checked and ensured that it was, and was updated to the latest version. I re-checked the code multiple times for errors, and I still cannot figure out why Raycast isn't being recognized. Below is the Unity script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.XR;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

public class TapToPlaceObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ARSessionOrigin arOrigin;
    private Pose placementPose;
    private bool placementPoseIsValid = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        arOrigin = FindObjectOfType<ARSessionOrigin>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdatePlacementPose();
    }

    private void UpdatePlacementPose()
    {
        var screenCenter = Camera.current.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
        var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
        arOrigin.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, TrackableType.Planes);

        placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            placementPose = hits[0].pose;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same *version* as the person who wrote the code is using?

Answer (score 0):

Gotta google your problems, my dude.

[From this post](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1632965/view.html):

> It seems that they have moved Raycast from ARSessionOrigin to ARRaycastManager in latest version. As mentioned in https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.0/manual/index.html, you need to "add an ARRaycastManager to the same GameObject as the ARSessionOrigin".

Edit - you should also pay very close attention to the publication date for any tutorials. Some aspects of Unity have been stable for a very long time but some things break on a new year's release. UI Toolkit, AR, DOTS, etc. are all examples off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to to try to adapt the script; I appreciate you pointing it out, and yeah the tutorial is 3 years old so I should try a newer one.